# How to draw a Circle with a center and a radius

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circles

How can I draw these pictures in LaTeX. I only know draw a circle but I need the point P in the center and a radius
[image]

Comment: Please show some compilable code.

Answer (score 9):

The most basic approach:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    
    \draw[fill=none](0,0) circle (1.0) node [black,yshift=-1.5cm] {Circle};
    \draw[fill=black](0,0) circle (1 pt) node [above] {\tiny P};
    \draw[](0,0) -- (1,0) node [midway,above] {$\scriptstyle a$};

    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A little bit less basic approach ...

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   (0,0) circle[radius=10mm] node [yshift=-13mm] {Circle};
\fill   (0,0) circle[radius=1pt]  node [above,font=\small] {$P$};
\draw   (0,0) -- node [above,font=\small] {$a$} (1,0);
%
\fill[gray] (3,0) circle[radius=10mm] node [text=black,yshift=-13mm] {Disc};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's *Disc* ;)

Comment: @SebGlav, you are right, on image I see e, but now I see that, my old eyes need new glasses ;-). Corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

Basic with `tkz-euclide` and some options of `TikZ`

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/P,2/0/A,6/0/Q,8/0/B}
\tkzDrawCircle(P,A)
\tkzDrawSegment(P,A)
\tkzDrawPoints(P,A)
\tkzLabelPoint[above](P){$P$}
\tkzLabelSegment(P,A){$a$}
\tkzLabelCircle[below=12pt](P,A)(-90){Circle}
\tkzFillCircle[lightgray](Q,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]